# Java : Compare same objects that they have same properties but do not points a same point in memory

Tags: java, android, object, compare

I have an custom adapter like this:

```
private List<User> items = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
public UserSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull
        List<User> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.items = objects;
    this.context = context;
}
```

when I want to find a position of object User that get from web api, the result of `public int getPosition(@Nullable User item)` is always **-1**. I think this is beacaus of my item that passed to the adapter is not just same as adapter user list inside although every thing is same but points to another point of memory.

So how I can compare two objects that have same properties but actualy seprated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should implement a `equals`/`hashCode` for the `User` object

Comment: thanks but it works without override hashCode and just with equals()

Comment: @Kenji, it will; but when overriding equals, you should always override hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `equals`/`hashCode` methods for the object that you compare. You can do it easily by pressing `Alt+Insert` inside your class and choose `equals() and hashCode()`. If your class has another fields which are custom type, for example

```
public class User {
     ...
     private Location location;
     ...
}
```

you have to implement `equals`/`hashCode` also for Location

Comment: it is useful too. what you mean location?

Comment: @Kenji, it is just example. I mean, if you have class `User` with custom field type (e.g. `Location`) and you don't implement `equals`/`hashCode` to `Location`, you will get non-equal objects of `User`, even if all fields are equal due to comparing `Location` by reference.